Fill Textboxes with Database Values on a Textbox Value Changed
My requirement is to fill textboxes with their corresponding value from database when a change is made in name textbox. For instance, if the value Mary is enter in name textbox then its corresponding row value from the database table such as spoon and plate should be displayed in store A and store B textbox respectively.



Id
Name
Store A
Store B




1
Julie
Knife
Pot


2
Mary
Spoon
Plate



Component.ts
 public orderForm = new FormGroup({
   Id: new FormControl(null),
   Name: new FormControl(null),
   StoreA: new FormControl(null),
   StoreB: new FormControl(null),    
 });

Name: string = ''; 
Store_A: string = ''; 
Store_B: string = ''; 

updateOtherFields(args: any): void {
  if (this.orderForm) {
    this.service.getData(args.orderForm.Name).subscribe((data) => {
      this.Store_A = args.itemData.StoreA;
      this.Store_B = args.itemData.StoreB;
  });
  } else {
    this.Store_A = '';
    this.Store_B = '';
  }
 }

html
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Name" (ngModelChange)="updateOtherFields()">
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="StoreA">
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="StoreB">

Expect output (textbox value)
Name   |Mary|
StoreA |Spoon|
StoreB |Plate|

Are you already handling multiple rows? Because based on your current code, with minor tweaks we can make it achieve your requirement, but taking it to a multi-row table increases the complexity, so please clarify this so I can provide and explain a better solution.

No, it's single row at a time. I;m using a router link from another component to pass value into the name textbox so that the other textboxes would be filled with its  corresponding row  value

@Milie24 please mention the problem you are facing!

@Naren Murah l don;t know how to fill storeA and storeB textbox from the database  when name textbox value changes

You are mixing template driven and reactive forms that is the problem, please go through the docs for each of the concepts, so that you can get a deep understanding of angular forms
Template driven forms docs
Angular reactive forms
Full code with comments explanation
Main.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { DdummyService } from './app/ddummy.service';
import { distinctUntilChanged, debounceTime } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <h1>Reactive Form Style</h1>
    <!-- form is essential for reactive forms [formGroup] stores the master form configured-->
    <form [formGroup]="orderForm">
      <!-- formControlName defines the property name of the formControl
      you defined in the orderForm -->
      <input type="text" formControlName="Name"/>
      <input type="text" formControlName="StoreA">
      <input type="text" formControlName="StoreB">
    </form>
    <h1>Template Driven Style<h1>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Name" (ngModelChange)="updateOtherFieldsTemplateDriven()">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Store_A">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="Store_B">
  `,
})
export class App {
  // reactive form style
  // configure the form with the respective properties
  public orderForm = new FormGroup({
    Id: new FormControl<string | null>(null),
    Name: new FormControl<string | null>(null),
    StoreA: new FormControl<string | null>(null),
    StoreB: new FormControl<string | null>(null),
  });
  constructor(private service: DdummyService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // we can use the valueChanges, which is an observable, we can subscribe
    // to know when the user typed, value changes fires multiple times.
    // we use rxjs operators to reduce the number of times

    this.orderForm
      ?.get('Name')
      ?.valueChanges.pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged(), // only if the value changes from previous value let it reach the subscribe
        debounceTime(500) // will wait for 500 ms after the user finishes
        // typing, this is a effective way to reduce unnecessary API calls
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        // when the code reaches here, the user changed the value!
        this.updateOtherFieldsReactive();
      });
  }

  updateOtherFieldsReactive() {
    // get the name typed from the order form
    const { Name } = this.orderForm.value;
    if (Name) {
      this.service.getData(Name).subscribe((data: any) => {
        // we can use patchValue to set the values on the form
        // this will directly be updated on the HTML
        if (Name) {
          this.orderForm.patchValue({
            StoreA: data.StoreA,
            StoreB: data.StoreB,
          });
        } else {
          this.orderForm.patchValue({
            StoreA: '',
            StoreB: '',
          });
        }
      });
    }
  }
  // template driven style
  // define the properties for the form, they will be binded to the html using ngModel, when you type it gets updated here, when you set a value it gets updated in html
  Name: string = '';
  Store_A: string = '';
  Store_B: string = '';

  // call the event from ngModel change
  updateOtherFieldsTemplateDriven(): void {
    // since what we type in name gets set directly in Name, just pass the value
    this.service.getData(this.Name).subscribe((data: any) => {
      // if the value is present directly assign it to the variable
      // to update the HTML with the new values
      if (data) {
        this.Store_A = data.StoreA;
        this.Store_B = data.StoreB;
      } else {
        this.Store_A = '';
        this.Store_B = '';
      }
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Service
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DdummyService {
  constructor() {}

  getData(name: string) {
    return of({
      StoreA: 'StoreA',
      StoreB: 'StoreB',
    });
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

Thank you for the update. I had included my service.ts code. I tried binding to remote server with your code, but it is not populating any value into the textboxes.

@User_K47 I just mocked the service to demo the code, please check what output your getting from the API and change the property access accordingly, we need to access that specific property and assign, the service mainly contains useless code, plz focus on the component code!
